# HTML5/CSS3 - Rotating HTML Path Vector Drawing on its own center within SVG CSS3 animation

Tags: html, css

I have an SVG-CSS3 animation that I made for a weather application I am creating. I have ran into something that I am not able to figure out myself.

I am trying to have the snowflakes also rotate on their own centers as they are falling. However I am not able to figure out how exactly I can get them to rotate on their own centers as they fall. Every rotation method I have tried seems to want to rotate it via the corner and center of the viewBox. I believe this is actually the correct result but not exactly what I am trying to do.

[Web Sample](https://notorioushaze.github.io/demo/index.html)

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/1eztdyus/1/)

Again, just trying to have the snowflakes also rotate as they fall on their own centers. Javascript additions are okay if ultimately required.

```css
/* -----   Holders  -------  */
.icon_holder {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

/* -----   Snowflakes  -------  */
.snowflakes {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    animation: snowflakeskey1 4s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.snowflakes1 {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    animation: snowflakeskey2 2s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.snowflakes2 {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    animation: snowflakeskey3 3s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.snowflakes3 {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    animation: snowflakeskey4 4s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.snowflakes4 {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    animation: snowflakeskey5 5s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes snowflakeskey1 {
  from{
    transform: translateY(-40px);
    opacity:1;
  }
  to{
   transform: translateY(125px);
    opacity:0;
  }
}

@keyframes snowflakeskey2 {
  from{
    transform: translateY(-30px);
    opacity:1;
  }
  to{
   transform: translateY(75px);
    opacity:0;
  }
}

@keyframes snowflakeskey3 {
  from{
    transform: translateY(-50px);
    opacity:1;
  }
  to{
   transform: translateY(100px);
    opacity:0;
  }
}

@keyframes snowflakeskey4 {
  from{
    transform: translateY(-40px);
    opacity:1;
  }
  to{
   transform: translateY(125px);
    opacity:0;
  }
}

@keyframes snowflakeskey5 {
  from{
    transform: translateY(-60px);
    opacity:1;
  }
  to{
   transform: translateY(150px);
    opacity:0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Icon</title>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/icons.css">


</head>

<body>
    <div class="icon_holder">
        <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="256" height="256" viewBox="0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve">
            <g id="snowflakes" class="snowflakes">
                <g transform="translate(120, 300)">
                    <path fill="#000000" transform="scale(0.075)" d="M438.237 355.927l-66.574-38.54 59.448-10.327c5.846-1.375 10.609-5.183 13.458-10.13 2.48-4.307 3.506-9.478 2.524-14.651-2.11-11.115-12.686-18.039-23.621-15.467l-85.423 31.115L255.914 256l82.136-41.926 85.423 31.115c10.936 2.572 21.512-4.352 23.621-15.467 2.111-11.115-5.046-22.209-15.981-24.781l-59.448-10.327 66.573-38.54c9.54-5.523 12.615-18.092 6.867-28.074-5.748-9.982-18.14-13.596-27.68-8.074l-66.574 38.54 20.805-56.787c3.246-10.782-2.758-22.542-13.413-26.268-10.654-3.725-21.922 1.997-25.168 12.779l-15.838 89.735-72.423 41.926V136l69.585-58.621c7.689-8.21 6.997-20.856-1.548-28.245-8.545-7.391-21.705-6.723-29.394 1.486l-38.644 46.46V20c0-11.046-9.318-20-20.813-20s-20.813 8.954-20.813 20v77.08l-38.644-46.46c-7.689-8.21-20.849-8.876-29.394-1.486-8.544 7.389-9.236 20.035-1.547 28.245L203.187 136v83.853l-72.423-41.926-15.838-89.736c-3.247-10.782-14.515-16.504-25.169-12.779-10.656 3.725-16.659 15.486-13.413 26.268l20.805 56.787-66.573-38.54c-9.54-5.523-21.933-1.908-27.68 8.074s-2.673 22.551 6.867 28.074l66.574 38.54-59.449 10.328C5.953 207.515-1.202 218.609.907 229.724c2.11 11.114 12.686 18.038 23.622 15.466l85.422-31.115L192.086 256l-82.136 41.926-85.423-31.115c-10.936-2.572-21.511 4.352-23.622 15.466-2.109 11.113 5.046 22.209 15.981 24.781l59.449 10.328-66.574 38.54C.223 361.449-2.852 374.018 2.896 384s18.14 13.597 27.68 8.074l66.574-38.54-20.805 56.786c-1.735 5.764-.828 11.805 2.02 16.751 2.48 4.307 6.433 7.784 11.392 9.517 10.655 3.725 21.923-1.997 25.169-12.779l15.838-89.736 72.423-41.926V376l-69.585 58.621c-7.69 8.21-6.997 20.855 1.547 28.245 8.544 7.388 21.705 6.723 29.394-1.487l38.644-46.46V492c0 11.046 9.318 20 20.813 20s20.813-8.954 20.813-20v-77.081l38.644 46.46c4.111 4.389 9.782 6.621 15.478 6.621 4.96 0 9.939-1.694 13.916-5.134 8.545-7.39 9.237-20.035 1.548-28.245L244.813 376v-83.853l72.423 41.926 15.838 89.736c3.246 10.782 14.514 16.504 25.168 12.779 10.653-3.726 16.659-15.487 13.412-26.268l-20.805-56.787 66.574 38.54c9.54 5.523 21.933 1.908 27.68-8.074 5.749-9.981 2.675-22.55-6.866-28.072z"/>
                </g>
            </g>
            <g id="snowflakes1" class="snowflakes1">
                <g transform="translate(180, 300)">
                    <path fill="#000000" transform="scale(0.075)" d="M438.237 355.927l-66.574-38.54 59.448-10.327c5.846-1.375 10.609-5.183 13.458-10.13 2.48-4.307 3.506-9.478 2.524-14.651-2.11-11.115-12.686-18.039-23.621-15.467l-85.423 31.115L255.914 256l82.136-41.926 85.423 31.115c10.936 2.572 21.512-4.352 23.621-15.467 2.111-11.115-5.046-22.209-15.981-24.781l-59.448-10.327 66.573-38.54c9.54-5.523 12.615-18.092 6.867-28.074-5.748-9.982-18.14-13.596-27.68-8.074l-66.574 38.54 20.805-56.787c3.246-10.782-2.758-22.542-13.413-26.268-10.654-3.725-21.922 1.997-25.168 12.779l-15.838 89.735-72.423 41.926V136l69.585-58.621c7.689-8.21 6.997-20.856-1.548-28.245-8.545-7.391-21.705-6.723-29.394 1.486l-38.644 46.46V20c0-11.046-9.318-20-20.813-20s-20.813 8.954-20.813 20v77.08l-38.644-46.46c-7.689-8.21-20.849-8.876-29.394-1.486-8.544 7.389-9.236 20.035-1.547 28.245L203.187 136v83.853l-72.423-41.926-15.838-89.736c-3.247-10.782-14.515-16.504-25.169-12.779-10.656 3.725-16.659 15.486-13.413 26.268l20.805 56.787-66.573-38.54c-9.54-5.523-21.933-1.908-27.68 8.074s-2.673 22.551 6.867 28.074l66.574 38.54-59.449 10.328C5.953 207.515-1.202 218.609.907 229.724c2.11 11.114 12.686 18.038 23.622 15.466l85.422-31.115L192.086 256l-82.136 41.926-85.423-31.115c-10.936-2.572-21.511 4.352-23.622 15.466-2.109 11.113 5.046 22.209 15.981 24.781l59.449 10.328-66.574 38.54C.223 361.449-2.852 374.018 2.896 384s18.14 13.597 27.68 8.074l66.574-38.54-20.805 56.786c-1.735 5.764-.828 11.805 2.02 16.751 2.48 4.307 6.433 7.784 11.392 9.517 10.655 3.725 21.923-1.997 25.169-12.779l15.838-89.736 72.423-41.926V376l-69.585 58.621c-7.69 8.21-6.997 20.855 1.547 28.245 8.544 7.388 21.705 6.723 29.394-1.487l38.644-46.46V492c0 11.046 9.318 20 20.813 20s20.813-8.954 20.813-20v-77.081l38.644 46.46c4.111 4.389 9.782 6.621 15.478 6.621 4.96 0 9.939-1.694 13.916-5.134 8.545-7.39 9.237-20.035 1.548-28.245L244.813 376v-83.853l72.423 41.926 15.838 89.736c3.246 10.782 14.514 16.504 25.168 12.779 10.653-3.726 16.659-15.487 13.412-26.268l-20.805-56.787 66.574 38.54c9.54 5.523 21.933 1.908 27.68-8.074 5.749-9.981 2.675-22.55-6.866-28.072z"/>
                </g>
            </g>
            <g id="snowflakes2" class="snowflakes2">
                <g transform="translate(240, 300)">
                    <path fill="#000000" transform="scale(0.075)" d="M438.237 355.927l-66.574-38.54 59.448-10.327c5.846-1.375 10.609-5.183 13.458-10.13 2.48-4.307 3.506-9.478 2.524-14.651-2.11-11.115-12.686-18.039-23.621-15.467l-85.423 31.115L255.914 256l82.136-41.926 85.423 31.115c10.936 2.572 21.512-4.352 23.621-15.467 2.111-11.115-5.046-22.209-15.981-24.781l-59.448-10.327 66.573-38.54c9.54-5.523 12.615-18.092 6.867-28.074-5.748-9.982-18.14-13.596-27.68-8.074l-66.574 38.54 20.805-56.787c3.246-10.782-2.758-22.542-13.413-26.268-10.654-3.725-21.922 1.997-25.168 12.779l-15.838 89.735-72.423 41.926V136l69.585-58.621c7.689-8.21 6.997-20.856-1.548-28.245-8.545-7.391-21.705-6.723-29.394 1.486l-38.644 46.46V20c0-11.046-9.318-20-20.813-20s-20.813 8.954-20.813 20v77.08l-38.644-46.46c-7.689-8.21-20.849-8.876-29.394-1.486-8.544 7.389-9.236 20.035-1.547 28.245L203.187 136v83.853l-72.423-41.926-15.838-89.736c-3.247-10.782-14.515-16.504-25.169-12.779-10.656 3.725-16.659 15.486-13.413 26.268l20.805 56.787-66.573-38.54c-9.54-5.523-21.933-1.908-27.68 8.074s-2.673 22.551 6.867 28.074l66.574 38.54-59.449 10.328C5.953 207.515-1.202 218.609.907 229.724c2.11 11.114 12.686 18.038 23.622 15.466l85.422-31.115L192.086 256l-82.136 41.926-85.423-31.115c-10.936-2.572-21.511 4.352-23.622 15.466-2.109 11.113 5.046 22.209 15.981 24.781l59.449 10.328-66.574 38.54C.223 361.449-2.852 374.018 2.896 384s18.14 13.597 27.68 8.074l66.574-38.54-20.805 56.786c-1.735 5.764-.828 11.805 2.02 16.751 2.48 4.307 6.433 7.784 11.392 9.517 10.655 3.725 21.923-1.997 25.169-12.779l15.838-89.736 72.423-41.926V376l-69.585 58.621c-7.69 8.21-6.997 20.855 1.547 28.245 8.544 7.388 21.705 6.723 29.394-1.487l38.644-46.46V492c0 11.046 9.318 20 20.813 20s20.813-8.954 20.813-20v-77.081l38.644 46.46c4.111 4.389 9.782 6.621 15.478 6.621 4.96 0 9.939-1.694 13.916-5.134 8.545-7.39 9.237-20.035 1.548-28.245L244.813 376v-83.853l72.423 41.926 15.838 89.736c3.246 10.782 14.514 16.504 25.168 12.779 10.653-3.726 16.659-15.487 13.412-26.268l-20.805-56.787 66.574 38.54c9.54 5.523 21.933 1.908 27.68-8.074 5.749-9.981 2.675-22.55-6.866-28.072z" />
                </g>
            </g>
            <g id="snowflakes3" class="snowflakes3">
                <g transform="translate(300, 300)">
                    <path fill="#000000" transform="scale(0.075)" d="M438.237 355.927l-66.574-38.54 59.448-10.327c5.846-1.375 10.609-5.183 13.458-10.13 2.48-4.307 3.506-9.478 2.524-14.651-2.11-11.115-12.686-18.039-23.621-15.467l-85.423 31.115L255.914 256l82.136-41.926 85.423 31.115c10.936 2.572 21.512-4.352 23.621-15.467 2.111-11.115-5.046-22.209-15.981-24.781l-59.448-10.327 66.573-38.54c9.54-5.523 12.615-18.092 6.867-28.074-5.748-9.982-18.14-13.596-27.68-8.074l-66.574 38.54 20.805-56.787c3.246-10.782-2.758-22.542-13.413-26.268-10.654-3.725-21.922 1.997-25.168 12.779l-15.838 89.735-72.423 41.926V136l69.585-58.621c7.689-8.21 6.997-20.856-1.548-28.245-8.545-7.391-21.705-6.723-29.394 1.486l-38.644 46.46V20c0-11.046-9.318-20-20.813-20s-20.813 8.954-20.813 20v77.08l-38.644-46.46c-7.689-8.21-20.849-8.876-29.394-1.486-8.544 7.389-9.236 20.035-1.547 28.245L203.187 136v83.853l-72.423-41.926-15.838-89.736c-3.247-10.782-14.515-16.504-25.169-12.779-10.656 3.725-16.659 15.486-13.413 26.268l20.805 56.787-66.573-38.54c-9.54-5.523-21.933-1.908-27.68 8.074s-2.673 22.551 6.867 28.074l66.574 38.54-59.449 10.328C5.953 207.515-1.202 218.609.907 229.724c2.11 11.114 12.686 18.038 23.622 15.466l85.422-31.115L192.086 256l-82.136 41.926-85.423-31.115c-10.936-2.572-21.511 4.352-23.622 15.466-2.109 11.113 5.046 22.209 15.981 24.781l59.449 10.328-66.574 38.54C.223 361.449-2.852 374.018 2.896 384s18.14 13.597 27.68 8.074l66.574-38.54-20.805 56.786c-1.735 5.764-.828 11.805 2.02 16.751 2.48 4.307 6.433 7.784 11.392 9.517 10.655 3.725 21.923-1.997 25.169-12.779l15.838-89.736 72.423-41.926V376l-69.585 58.621c-7.69 8.21-6.997 20.855 1.547 28.245 8.544 7.388 21.705 6.723 29.394-1.487l38.644-46.46V492c0 11.046 9.318 20 20.813 20s20.813-8.954 20.813-20v-77.081l38.644 46.46c4.111 4.389 9.782 6.621 15.478 6.621 4.96 0 9.939-1.694 13.916-5.134 8.545-7.39 9.237-20.035 1.548-28.245L244.813 376v-83.853l72.423 41.926 15.838 89.736c3.246 10.782 14.514 16.504 25.168 12.779 10.653-3.726 16.659-15.487 13.412-26.268l-20.805-56.787 66.574 38.54c9.54 5.523 21.933 1.908 27.68-8.074 5.749-9.981 2.675-22.55-6.866-28.072z" />
                </g>
            </g>
            <g id="snowflakes4" class="snowflakes4">
                <g transform="translate(360, 300)">
                    <path fill="#000000" transform="scale(0.075)" d="M438.237 355.927l-66.574-38.54 59.448-10.327c5.846-1.375 10.609-5.183 13.458-10.13 2.48-4.307 3.506-9.478 2.524-14.651-2.11-11.115-12.686-18.039-23.621-15.467l-85.423 31.115L255.914 256l82.136-41.926 85.423 31.115c10.936 2.572 21.512-4.352 23.621-15.467 2.111-11.115-5.046-22.209-15.981-24.781l-59.448-10.327 66.573-38.54c9.54-5.523 12.615-18.092 6.867-28.074-5.748-9.982-18.14-13.596-27.68-8.074l-66.574 38.54 20.805-56.787c3.246-10.782-2.758-22.542-13.413-26.268-10.654-3.725-21.922 1.997-25.168 12.779l-15.838 89.735-72.423 41.926V136l69.585-58.621c7.689-8.21 6.997-20.856-1.548-28.245-8.545-7.391-21.705-6.723-29.394 1.486l-38.644 46.46V20c0-11.046-9.318-20-20.813-20s-20.813 8.954-20.813 20v77.08l-38.644-46.46c-7.689-8.21-20.849-8.876-29.394-1.486-8.544 7.389-9.236 20.035-1.547 28.245L203.187 136v83.853l-72.423-41.926-15.838-89.736c-3.247-10.782-14.515-16.504-25.169-12.779-10.656 3.725-16.659 15.486-13.413 26.268l20.805 56.787-66.573-38.54c-9.54-5.523-21.933-1.908-27.68 8.074s-2.673 22.551 6.867 28.074l66.574 38.54-59.449 10.328C5.953 207.515-1.202 218.609.907 229.724c2.11 11.114 12.686 18.038 23.622 15.466l85.422-31.115L192.086 256l-82.136 41.926-85.423-31.115c-10.936-2.572-21.511 4.352-23.622 15.466-2.109 11.113 5.046 22.209 15.981 24.781l59.449 10.328-66.574 38.54C.223 361.449-2.852 374.018 2.896 384s18.14 13.597 27.68 8.074l66.574-38.54-20.805 56.786c-1.735 5.764-.828 11.805 2.02 16.751 2.48 4.307 6.433 7.784 11.392 9.517 10.655 3.725 21.923-1.997 25.169-12.779l15.838-89.736 72.423-41.926V376l-69.585 58.621c-7.69 8.21-6.997 20.855 1.547 28.245 8.544 7.388 21.705 6.723 29.394-1.487l38.644-46.46V492c0 11.046 9.318 20 20.813 20s20.813-8.954 20.813-20v-77.081l38.644 46.46c4.111 4.389 9.782 6.621 15.478 6.621 4.96 0 9.939-1.694 13.916-5.134 8.545-7.39 9.237-20.035 1.548-28.245L244.813 376v-83.853l72.423 41.926 15.838 89.736c3.246 10.782 14.514 16.504 25.168 12.779 10.653-3.726 16.659-15.487 13.412-26.268l-20.805-56.787 66.574 38.54c9.54 5.523 21.933 1.908 27.68-8.074 5.749-9.981 2.675-22.55-6.866-28.072z" />
                </g>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried using solutions using calc? If you rotate and move towards the pivot corner at the same time, you should be able to pull it off. (nvm, remembered thing, posted below)

Comment: found this article: http://danielcwilson.com/blog/2017/10/all-the-transform-ways/ , Web Animations API might be what you are looking for, it's not supported well at the moment though.

Comment: @ViktorHabchak Thanks, I will give it a read through and see if anything on there can point me into the right direction.

Comment: The more I get into this, the more I am thinking this isn't possible with just straight CSS. It's my understanding that it needs a fixed point to spin to. You can't move that spin point while its also animating that spin. You also can't define the center of a path/polygon to spin to. Only appears to be origins of the viewBox itself.

Answer (score 0):

Change the transform origin property

transform-origin: 50% 50%;

Comment: transform-origin: 50% 50%; Causes the snowflake to spin center of viewBox instead of center of the snowflake (itself) as it falls.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need any kind of snowflakes animation I have a demo here that might be useful.

Apologies if it's not.

[Demo on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/xn-snowflakes-demo?embed=1&file=index.ts&hideExplorer=1)